# Battle.net (Wine) Reclaiming disk space / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine, games, lutris

I've been playing Diablo II: Resurrected successfully on Ubuntu 20.04 so far but since a new patch has been released, I get a message of "Reclaiming disk space" in Battle.net and the game does not update. I have +200 GB of free disk space and I've read several posts where people experience this kind of problems with Wine but so far no solution has worked for me.

I'd like to ask the community for help diagnosing my problem (I am no Linux expert, so I may need thorough explainations and step by step instructions).

My first attempt was to reinstall the game, but it was not successful. 30 GB game gets installed but a small (IDK exactly but around 150 MB) patch does not.

Then I thought maybe the "free disk space" was related to my /home directory so I deleted some stuff from there, but the same message keeps coming up on Battle.net tool.

I'll try to keep editing the question with your sugestions so the description is better and more complete.

Thanks!

EDIT 1 (@Sheldon):

```
san15895@san15895-TUF-Gaming-FX505DT-FX505DT:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,5G     0  7,5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   19M  1,5G   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  468G  228G  217G  52% /
tmpfs           7,6G   71M  7,5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,6G     0  7,6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop3      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1376
/dev/loop1      111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12834
/dev/loop4      248M  248M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop6      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop7      249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop8      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1405
/dev/loop10     425M  425M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20/1
/dev/loop11     153M  153M     0 100% /snap/skype/209
/dev/loop12      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop13     556M  556M     0 100% /snap/freecad-ppd/244
/dev/loop14      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15534
/dev/loop16     425M  425M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8
/dev/loop17      83M   83M     0 100% /snap/discord/131
/dev/loop18      83M   83M     0 100% /snap/discord/132
/dev/loop19     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop20      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop21      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop22     296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop23      44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/loop24     153M  153M     0 100% /snap/skype/206
/dev/loop25      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop26     112M  112M     0 100% /snap/core/12941
/dev/loop27     296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2288
/dev/loop28     261M  261M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop29      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop30     320M  320M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/7
/dev/sda1       224G   32K  224G   1% /mnt/3DBA-C5C6
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  5,3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   24K  1,6G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           1,6G   60K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        58G  468M   58G   1% /media/san15895/USB-Stick
/dev/loop31     556M  556M     0 100% /snap/freecad-ppd/245
```

EDIT 2 (@Sheldon):

```
san15895@san15895-TUF-Gaming-FX505DT-FX505DT:~$ lutris battle.net
2022-04-26 12:25:35,370: Starting Lutris 0.5.10
2022-04-26 12:25:35,415: No folder at /home/san15895/.local/share/lutris/runners/retroarch/
2022-04-26 12:25:35,445: Using NVIDIA drivers 470.103.01 for x86_64
2022-04-26 12:25:35,446: GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
2022-04-26 12:25:35,446: GPU: 10DE:1F91 1043:109F (nvidia drivers)
2022-04-26 12:25:35,446: GPU: 1002:15D8 1043:18F1 (amdgpu drivers)
2022-04-26 12:25:37,770: Startup complete
Started initial process 23354 from gamemoderun /home/san15895/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton7-1-x86_64/bin/wine /home/san15895/Games/battlenet/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Battle.net/Battle.net.exe
Start monitoring process.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
wineserver: using server-side synchronization.
wine: RLIMIT_NICE is <= 20, unable to use setpriority safely
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
[0426/122544.857:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(142)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
[0426/122545.677:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1397)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: Module not found. (0x7E)
[0426/122545.680:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1405)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msvproc.dll: Module not found. (0x7E)
[0426/122545.963:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1320)] DXVAVDA fatal error: Could not load msmpeg2vdec.dll: Module not found. (0x7E)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
[0426/122546.464:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(142)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
[0426/122547.490:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(40)] rx::SwapChain11::reset(615): Could not create additional swap chains or offscreen surfaces, HRESULT: 0x80070057
[0426/122547.490:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(787)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglCreateWindowSurface: Bad allocation.
[0426/122547.490:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1394)] eglCreateWindowSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[0426/122547.491:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(450)] ContextResult::kSurfaceFailure: Failed to create surface.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
[0426/122746.022:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1397)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: Module not found. (0x7E)
[0426/122746.024:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1405)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msvproc.dll: Module not found. (0x7E)
```

Comment: @Sheldon - Done.

Comment: 1) What is the complete message you get when updating, or is it just "Reclaiming disk space"? 2) Can you start wine/lutris/battlenet from a shell? Some applications provide more information when starting them from a shell. You will get the same graphical messages, but there might be more information/text logged to the shell.

Comment: 1) Just that, reclaiming disk space and then it allows to play without updaing. 2) Posted execution from shell.

Comment: I should have asked more precise: Did you copy that log *after* you tried to install the update?

Comment: "I've read several posts where people experience this kind of problems with Wine but so far no solution has worked for me." -> Do you have any links to these posts?

Comment: Yes, as soon as Battle.net is on screen it tries to automatically update and message appears. Then I tried to manually check for updates and same message. From what I see not much info about this is on those logs.

Comment: I haven't saved the links to other posts, sorry. I was going through this a few days ago and couldn't reach a solution. That's why today I decided to post.

Comment: If you run out of ideas, you can get more information with `strace`. Since strace can produce a lot (!) of output (too long to post it here), this might be too much for a Linux newbie. But strace is a good tool for analysing such problems. Here is an example of strace being used to analyze the behavior of Lutris: https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues/875#issuecomment-390399519

Comment: Well, while we wait for someone else to join the discussion I'll give it a go, following that example. Maybe I catch something funny in the log and post just that here. Thanks a lot for your contribution here!